# CSS: Laying out child columns sticking to left & right border of parent element

Tags: css, layout

Laying out child columns where leftmost and rightmost columns stick to left and right border of parent container 
has always been a challenge to me (image attached) and I would like to know the correct way (the way in which an experienced designer would do it) to doing it in css.

As in the the link image, there are 4 child column .
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27899629/stack/treatment-block.png

The way I coded it: 
**CSS**

```
#treatments-block {
    background-color: #FAF1E2;
    min-height: 400px;
}

.treatment-row {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}

.treatment {
    width: 17%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    float: left;
}

.treatment img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="treatments-block">
    <div class="centrewrap">

        <div class="section-title light-brown-color">SKIN TREATMENTS AVAILABLE</div>
        <div class="treatment-row" style="margin-top:0">

            <div class="treatment">
                <img src="images/botox-fillers-thumb.jpg">
                <h3>Botox & Fillers</h3>
                <p>Some cool text in here some cool text in here..</p>
            </div>

            <div class="treatment">
                <img src="images/botox-fillers-thumb.jpg">
                <h3>Botox & Fillers</h3>
                <p>Some cool text in here some cool text in here..</p>
            </div>

            <div class="treatment">
                <img src="images/botox-fillers-thumb.jpg">
                <h3>Botox & Fillers</h3>
                <p>Some cool text in here some cool text in here..</p>
            </div>

            <div class="treatment" style="margin-right:0;">
                <img src="images/botox-fillers-thumb.jpg">
                <h3>Botox & Fillers</h3>
                <p>Some cool text in here some cool text in here..</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you consider using CSS3 flexbox specification?

Answer (score 0):

To style the last element of a parent element, you can use the :last-child pseudo class. In your example like this:

CSS:

```
.treatment-row{margin-top:10px;border:1px solid red;overflow:auto;}
.treatment{width:22%; margin-right: 4%; float:left;}
.treatment img{max-width:100%}
.treatment:last-child{float:right; margin-right: 0}
```

Note: the name `"last-child"` is a little missleading, because it doesn't refer to the last child of an element, but to the last child of the parent element. E.g.:

For a list of `li`s in a `ul`, you need to use `li:last-child` to select the last `li` in that list